# How to implicitly infer specific type

Tags: typescript, react-native

I've been trying to implicitly infer the specific type of `screens` in the code down below, without hard coding the type in there.

The expected Result:

```js
{
    element: React.FC
    name: 'Explore' | 'Hates' | 'Messages' | 'Profile'
}[]
```

The actual Result:

```js
{
    element: React.FC
    name: string
}[]
```

these are the two ways I tried it and both didn't work:

```js
interface IScreen<T> {
    element: React.FC;
    name: T
}

function test<T>(screen: React.FC, name: T): IScreen<T> {
    const obj = {
        element: screen,
        name: name
    };
    return obj
};

const screens: IScreen[] = [
    test(ExploreScreen, 'Explore'),
    test(HatesScreen, 'Hates'),
    test(MessagesScreen,'Messages'),
    test(ProfileScreen,'Profile'),
];
```

```js
interface IScreen<T> {
    element: React.FC;
    name: T
}

const screens: IScreen[] = [
    { element: ExploreScreen, name: 'Explore' },
    { element: HatesScreen, name: 'Hates' },
    { element: MessagesScreen, name: 'Messages' },
    { element: ProfileScreen, name: 'Profile' },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt very close to what you need:

```
const screens = [
    test(ExploreScreen, 'Explore' as const),
    test(HatesScreen, 'Hates' as const),
    test(MessagesScreen,'Messages' as const),
    test(ProfileScreen,'Profile' as const),
];
```